# Selecting Date and Time intervals from MYSQL

Tags: php, mysql

**Background**:
I have a database table filled with over `500 rows`. The data is from a websites `json` API. There is a column called `created_at` which mimics the `json` API not the local row `created_at` time. Here is an example of the date / time format from the API `2009-12-10T20:08:00+0000`. The column in the database has the type `varchar` which may be problematic later on.

**Problem:**
I to wish setup a specific query or if a query cannot be achieved run all of the database rows through a loop. I want the ability to query posts at set date intervals, for instance, todays date is Aug 28th 2011, I want the weekly, monthly, and yearly posts that match that date.

Weekly would look like this (ie. Aug 28th 2011, Aug 21th 2011, Aug 14th 2011, Aug 07th 2011 ).

Monthly would look like this (ie. Aug 28th 2011, Jul 28th 2011,Jun 28th 2011, May 28th 2011 ).

Yearly would look like this (ie. Aug 28th 2011, Aug 28th 2010, Aug 28th 2009 ).

**Special cases**
If one of these is **not present** I would like the ability to retrieve whichever preceding or proceeding row date is closer to the date requested. If their are **multiple rows for one date** I just want the first one.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

**UPDATE**
I have added a column with the type `datetime` and have pulled and updated the rows with the new `created_at_datetime` column which correspondes to `date('Y-m-d H:i:s', $jsonDate)`. I still have little idea how to form the mysql query.

Comment: It would make your life significantly easier if you converted that JSON date string to a native MySQL `datetime` format. For example: `$mysqlDate = date('Y-m-d H:i:s', $jsonDate);` would then allow you to work with the times much more easily.

Comment: Then what? After it is converted I still have little idea how I would get it to query the way I want.

Comment: Sorry I can't be of more help; I'm not particularly good with MySQL, although have a look around for `MySQL INTERVAL` on Google; that should get you somewhere.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have to convert the date, use strftime(), http://php.net/manual/en/function.strftime.php

Use srttotime() to calculate dates in the past/future; get the previous month and last day of the month, then add a 24:59:59 signaling the last possible second of the month, and a 00:00:00 for the 1st possible second.

To get only 1 result in the database call, use LIMIT 1, and order by asc/desc.